# MS Access: Fill in missing values by group for string variables

Tags: ms-access

I am working with a MS Access database (and I am completely new to it). Basically, my data has the following structure, where "Name" and "Code" are string variables.

Table:

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | AB-1 |
| Name 1 |  |
| Name 2 | CD-8 |
| Name 2 |  |
| Name 2 |  |
| Name 3 | XY-6 |
| Name 4 | FG-5 |
| Name 4 |  |

I want to fill in the missing values for "Code" by "Name", so that I get

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | AB-1 |
| Name 1 | AB-1 |
| Name 2 | CD-8 |
| Name 2 | CD-8 |
| Name 2 | CD-8 |
| Name 3 | XY-6 |
| Name 4 | FG-5 |
| Name 4 | FG-5 |

What would I have to do?

Comment: What you should do is have a table of unique names and associated code. Why are you repeating name and code data? What other fields are in this table? Also, Name is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as field names.

Comment: The table contains further cariables, which are not constant within "Name", so I have to keep the stucture from the example.

Comment: Don't really understand that, but if you absolutely must do this, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Table1.Code = DLookUp("Code","Table1","Name='" & [Name] & "' AND NOT Code IS NULL") 
WHERE Code IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Follow-up question: The code works perfectly for data that I entered directly into the table. When I enter new data to the table using a front end form, however, missing "Code" variables are not updated when running the query. What might be the problem?

Comment: Possibly data entered via form hasn't been committed to table when you execute code. Record is committed when 1) close table/query/form or 2) move to another record or 3) run code to save. Another topic, start another question if you need more help.